# How do I remove the protection of a chest-plate in Bukkit

Tags: java, bukkit

I need to remove the protection of a chest-plate, as if the player was without a chest-plate when take damage.

Answer (score 1):

You could theorethically change all chestplates armor strength to `0` using `Attributes`.

[Here](https://github.com/gvlfm78/BukkitOldCombatMechanics/blob/master/src/main/java/gvlfm78/plugin/OldCombatMechanics/module/ModuleOldArmourStrength.java) you have a possibly good implementation of that.

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions (less than 1.12 I believe) you can use `DamageModifier.ARMOR` in a `EntityDamageByEntityEvent` like this:

```
@EventHandler   
public void damageEvent(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {
    event.setDamage(DamageModifier.ARMOR, 0);
}
```

The above code disables armor's "armor" for all entities, to only make it for players is your task. Do not forget registering the listener.

In newer versions the method is deprecated and very likely to be removed in the future

Good luck!

Comment: Hey , Thanks but i already knew it. this remove all armor protection , i only want to remove chestplate protection :(